Spinner decoration
This is my Spinner:
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/categories"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"/>

An it looks like this:

When I add a background to it:
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"

it looks like this:

Notice how the small downward triangle at the end vanished. Why? Is it possible to have a background on my Spinner and still retain the triangle?
This is spinner_background.xml:
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/design_default_color_primary" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

